# Webflux nested router on root always returns 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a RouterFunction with nested routes in it, everything except one route is doing with I think they're supposed to do. 
But when I try to call one of the root routes inside a nested route, I always get a 404. This only happens with that particular route and when I change it from root to "/foo" it starts working.

code:

```
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> productRouter(final ProductHandler handler) {
        return nest(path(apiPath + BASE_PATH),
                route(POST("/").and(contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::handleCreateProduct)
                        .andRoute(GET("/{id}"), handler::handleGetProductById)
                        .andRoute(PUT("/").and(contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::handleUpdateProduct)
                        .andRoute(GET("/"), handler::handleGetAllProducts)
                        .andNest(path("/category"),
                                route(POST("/").and(contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::handleCreateProductCategory)
                                        .andRoute(GET("/{id}"), handler::handleGetProductCategoryById)
                                        .andRoute(GET("/"), handler::handleGetAllProductCategories)
                                        .andRoute(GET("/search/{name}"), handler::handleGetProductCategoriesByName)
                        ))
                .andNest(path("/brand"),
                        route(POST("/").and(contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::handleCreateProductBrand)
                                .andRoute(GET("/"), handler::handleGetAllProductBrands)
                                .andRoute(GET("/{id}"), handler::handleGetProductBrandById));
    }
```

The route that's not working right is the following:

```
.andRoute(GET("/"), handler::handleGetAllProductCategories)
```

The strange thing is under the root path and brands path I do the exact same thing and those routes work.

Thanks for helping out

Comment: could you provide more information? What are the values for `apiPath` and `BASE_PATH`?

Comment: apiPath = "/api/v1" and BASE_PATH = "/products"

Comment: so I've figured out that "/api/v1/products/category/" returns a 404 but when I use "/api/v1/products/category//" it returns the list I'm expecting, I've seen that this was a bug on github somewhere but can't seem to find it again, I'm using spring-boot 2.1.2 with webflux 5.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't manage to reproduce this problem on Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE, with the following:

```
@Configuration
public class RouterConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> productRouter() {
        return nest(path("/test"),
                route(GET("/"), serverRequest -> ServerResponse.ok().syncBody("TEST"))
                        .andNest(path("/other"),
                                route(GET("/{id}"), serverRequest -> ServerResponse.ok().syncBody("ID"))
                                .andRoute(GET("/"), serverRequest -> ServerResponse.ok().syncBody("OTHER"))));
    }
}
```

I'm getting the result:

```
➜  ~ http :8080/test
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

TEST

➜  ~ http :8080/test/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

TEST

➜  ~ http :8080/test/other
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

OTHER

➜  ~ http :8080/test/other/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

OTHER

➜  ~ http :8080/test/other/something
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

ID
```

If you manage to reproduce this problem in a sample application, please create an issue on the [Spring Framework issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues), as I didn't manage to find an existing issue for that. Please provide a sample project there that we can clone and run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've found what the problem is, it's because there's a pathVariable on the "/test" path (in your example), and webflux is considering the "other" path as a path variable, I'll create an issue in the Spring issue tracker, but thx for helping me look into it!

Comment: It might not be an issue then - keep in mind that router functions are about the first route that matches. So ordering is important unlike the annotation model. If you create an issue, please provide a reduced sample we can run. Thanks!

Comment: thx for the help Brian, I've figured it out with the help I got from you

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is an open bug in Weblux about mapping the root element : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9785

You should either use redirection or no use the "/" mapping.

Comment: this is a different problem; the issue you're pointing at is about supporting welcome page support in Spring Boot. In this case, the OP is trying to match a route under a nested path.

Comment: Yes you are right. I faced it recently, I thought it would apply for base root mapping too

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brian Clozel's comment I was able to figure it out

```
keep in mind that router functions are about the first route that matches.
```

So with that in mind I restructured my RouterFunctions in the following way:

```
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> productRouter(final ProductHandler handler) {

        return nest(path(apiPath + BASE_PATH),
                route(method(HttpMethod.POST).and(accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)), handler::handleCreateProduct)
                        .andNest(path("/category"),
                                route(GET("/{id}"), handler::handleGetProductCategoryById)
                                        .andRoute(method(HttpMethod.POST).and(contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::handleCreateProductCategory)
                                        .andRoute(GET("/search/{name}"), handler::handleGetProductCategoriesByName)
                                        .andRoute(method(HttpMethod.GET), handler::handleGetAllProductCategories))
                        .andNest(path("/brand"),
                                route(method(HttpMethod.POST).and(contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::handleCreateProductBrand)
                                        .andRoute(GET("/{id}"), handler::handleGetProductBrandById)
                                        .andRoute(method(HttpMethod.GET), handler::handleGetAllProductBrands))
                        .andRoute(GET("/{id}/pdf"), handler::handlaProductDetailsPdf)
                        .andRoute(GET("/{id}"), handler::handleGetProductById)
                        .andRoute(method(HttpMethod.PUT).and(contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::handleUpdateProduct)
                        .andRoute(method(HttpMethod.GET), handler::handleGetAllProducts));
}
```

I've moved the /category and /brand path both higher in the chain than the root path and it works as expected.

Again thx Brian for the help!